# Ruby Set and Ruby Array, are they stored in the same way using postgresql?

Tags: arrays, ruby, postgresql, set

I couldn't find any information related to my question on the official documentation.

The situation is, I need to store a list of ids on my ruby object, so I decided to use a set instead of an array to avoid duplicity and have faster included? answer.

The question is, if I'll have any trouble with postgresql when I tried to save my Object with this attribute setted up as a Set?

I hope being clear with my question.

Thanks in advance.
Regards.

**EDIT:**

I solved it.
I did what I should have done from the beginning, have create table with the 2FKs and that's it!

Problem solved!

Comment: It would be helpful to give a more specific example of your model.  Have you written any code yet? Also "will I have any trouble?"  is a very ambiguous question as we don't know what "trouble" means.

Comment: Actually, I don't really understand your question, but: If you just want to store your Ruby objects and retrieve them later (i.e. not performing SQL queries on them), you could [marshal](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Marshal.html) them into a String and store the string. For the relationship between `Set` and `Array`: You can convert a `Set` into an `Array` and back, if this helps you.

Answer (score 1):

PostgreSQL doesn't know anything about Ruby. You cannot store Ruby objects in PostgreSQL. You will have to translate the Ruby objects into something that PostgreSQL understands (text, numbers, clobs, blobs, etc.) first.

In other words: the object is stored in PostgreSQL in exactly the way you write the code to store it.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried storing an array with sqlite3, which did not work. In my tutorials they did mention that it's possible to store an array in a column with Postgres.

However, a better way to store arrays for your model attributes would be [Active Record Associations](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association).

A has_many association may be what you are looking for.